# How can I remove the prefix "Appendix" from toc?

Tags: titlesec, appendices, titletoc, appendix

I am an spanish user. But I found here are a great community, so I have to ask. After review many post, and questions in Tex StackExchange. The problem keep me stuck  and watching the code, I don't could think a simple solution.

I want to solve the same style of titlecontent for Appendix as Section in TOC. I have tried format it from preamble (for appendix) but it didn't happen, the next code is the ultimate way I tried and works.

Here is the preamble:

```
\titlecontents{section}
  [0cm]
  {\vspace{0.1cm}\filright\large \bfseries}
  {Sección \contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{0em} \hfill \\ }
  {Sección \contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{0em} \hfill \\   }
  {{\mdseries \hfill \contentspage}}
\begin{appendices}
```

And this the appendix section:

```
\begin{appendices}
  \titlecontents{section}
  [0cm]
  {\vspace{0.1cm}\filright\large \bfseries}
  {Apéndice \contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{0em} \hfill \\ }
  {Apéndice \contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{0em} \hfill \\ }
  {{\mdseries \hfill \contentspage}}

\titleformat{\section}[display]{\raggedleft \bfseries \LARGE \setstretch{1.3}}{  
  \begin{spacing}{0}
  \parskip=0pt
  \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\ 
  \vspace{10pt}
  {Apéndice \thesection}\\
  \vspace{10pt}
  \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
  \end{spacing}
  \vspace*{-20pt}
  }{3pt}{#1} 

    "sections section of appendix"
\end{appendices}
```

of course the necessary packages have been loaded with the "usepackage". But let me show you the options i am using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp}
  \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
  \usepackage[tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm]{geometry}
  \usepackage[labelfont=bf,width=0.75\textwidth,font=small,skip=5pt,textfont=it]{caption}  
  \usepackage{float, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, graphicx, eso-pic}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \usepackage{tabularx}
  \usepackage{setspace}
  \usepackage{microtype}
  \usepackage{parskip}
  \usepackage{gensymb}
  \usepackage{xurl}
  \usepackage{float}
  \usepackage{xurl}
  \usepackage{xcolor}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage{mathptmx}
  \usepackage{natbib}
  \usepackage{titletoc}
  \usepackage{setspace}
  \usepackage{chngcntr}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \usepackage[pagestyles ,newparttoc, explicit]{titlesec}%
  \usepackage{stackengine}
```

The results in appendix are:

---

### [image]

And it is the TOC I want to solve:

---

### [image]

---

**The real problem there is the double "Apendice"**, I just want the first one with its label "A", and only see the title of appendix. Here is the format give to me:

---

### [image]

If I have to guess the problem, in titlecontent definition, the appendix pre formated section takes the appendix with the contentlabel, and is like a single block. I am understanding why the section format for normal sections in the document has to take that options to work with number separately, to separate the "seccion 1" of "Name section".

Thanks for reading! and if have and idea to solve it, then more!

Answer (score 1):

Solved! It was very very simple, the question maybe I would to keep here to answering someone in the future.

Just format the appendixname, with:

```
\addto\captionsspanish{%
\renewcommand\listfigurename{Figuras}
\renewcommand\listtablename{Tablas}
\renewcommand\contentsname{}
\renewcommand\appendixname{}
\renewcommand\appendixpagename{}}
```

I didn't notice I has the format for appendix there, not at all I don't noticed the difference between appendixname and appendixpagename, so there is. This is my TOC:

[image]

Comment: You've not shown us how you create the document, so it's hard to tell for sure, but it looks like you have some space in front of **Datasheets** that might not be desired.

Comment: Have you been able to remove just the "Apéndice" from the TOC entry? For example, "A. Revisiones" instead of "Apéndice A. Revisiones"?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get here for a while. The spacing in the subitems of the "Appendices" looks not annoying for me; for sure, this will require more investigation how to deal delete it @Teepeemm . And about the "A. Revisiones" instead of "Apendice A. Revisiones", i just make the format give to me. Thanks by the comments, I appreciate this a lot.